# How to strip line breaks from BeautifulSoup get text method

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a following output after scraping a web page

```
       text
Out[50]: 
['\nAbsolute FreeBSD, 2nd Edition\n',
'\nAbsolute OpenBSD, 2nd Edition\n',
'\nAndroid Security Internals\n',
'\nApple Confidential 2.0\n',
'\nArduino Playground\n',
'\nArduino Project Handbook\n',
'\nArduino Workshop\n',
'\nArt of Assembly Language, 2nd Edition\n',
'\nArt of Debugging\n',
'\nArt of Interactive Design\n',]
```

I need to strip \n from above list while iterating over it. Following is my code

```
text = []
for name in web_text:
   a = name.get_text()
   text.append(a)
```

Answer (score 7):

Rather than calling `.strip()` explicitly, use the `strip` argument:

```
a = name.get_text(strip=True)
```

This would also remove the extra whitespace and newline characters in the children texts if any.

Answer (score 3):

Just like you would [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) any other string:

```
text = []
for name in web_text:
   a = name.get_text().strip()
   text.append(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```
stripedText = [ t.strip() for t in text ]
```

Which outputs:

```
>>> stripedText
['Absolute FreeBSD, 2nd Edition', 'Absolute OpenBSD, 2nd Edition', 'Android Security Internals', 'Apple Confidential 2.0', 'Arduino Playground', 'Arduino Project Handbook', 'Arduino Workshop', 'Art of Assembly Language, 2nd Edition', 'Art of Debugging', 'Art of Interactive Design']
```

Answer (score 0):

The following way helps you to strip \n from above list while iterating over it.

```
>>> web_text = ['\nAbsolute FreeBSD, 2nd Edition\n',
... '\nAbsolute OpenBSD, 2nd Edition\n',
... '\nAndroid Security Internals\n',
... '\nApple Confidential 2.0\n',
... '\nArduino Playground\n',
... '\nArduino Project Handbook\n',
... '\nArduino Workshop\n',
... '\nArt of Assembly Language, 2nd Edition\n',
... '\nArt of Debugging\n',
... '\nArt of Interactive Design\n',]

>>> text = []
>>> for line in web_text:
...     a = line.strip()
...     text.append(a)
...
>>> text
['Absolute FreeBSD, 2nd Edition', 'Absolute OpenBSD, 2nd Edition', 'Android 
Security Internals', 'Apple Confidential 2.0', 'Arduino Playground', 
'Arduino Project Handbook', 'Arduino Workshop', 'Art of Assembly Language, 
2nd Edition', 'Art of Debugging', 'Art of Interactive Design']
```