# ignoring \n when using .text in beautiful soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Sorry for the beginner question:

I have extracted something along the lines of:

```
<span class="a-size-small a-color-price">
                    $319.99
</span>
```

but when I try to dig one step further and just try to get the contents with .text, I get this:

```
'\n    $319.99\n'
```

is there an elegant way I can ignore the line breaks and whitespace and just get the value?

thank you!

Comment: IIRC if you call `.strip()` on the text (`element.text.strip()`) it should remove all the whitespace.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to strip line breaks from BeautifulSoup get text method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39870290/how-to-strip-line-breaks-from-beautifulsoup-get-text-method)

Comment: thank you! .strip() worked.

Comment: Also depends how you are *finding* the text -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206380/python-beautifulsoup-how-to-remove-all-tags-from-an-element.