# Web scraping in python; Output to excel returns HTML instead of the data frame

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I'm new to python and practicing web scraping. I was writing a code to get all the movie names and the the consecutive year of the movies. I got the result into a dataframe, but when i am exporting to excel, its showing as the html code. Thanks in advance.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

pages=np.arange(1,2,1)
pwd = os.getcwd()

yify = pd.DataFrame (columns = ['Title', 'Year'])

#looping through different pages
for page in pages:
    page='https://yts.mx/browse-movies?page='+str(page)
    data=requests.get(page).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')

    #looping through all the movie names and years
    for row in soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'browse-movie-bottom'):
        title=row.find('a', class_ = 'browse-movie-title')
        years=row.find('div', class_ = 'browse-movie-year')
        yify=yify.append({'Title': title, 'Year':years},ignore_index=True)

yify.head()
output.to_excel(pwd + '\\Yify_Test_Output.xlsx', index=False )
```

Comment: What is the **ouput**? Where is it initialized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
for row in soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'browse-movie-bottom'):
        title=row.find('a', class_ = 'browse-movie-title').text.strip()
        years=row.find('div', class_ = 'browse-movie-year').text.strip()
```

As a short explanation: the OP was retrieving the actual HTML element, including HTML tags. You extract the text from the element with `<html_element>.text`.

Comment: Thank you so much @platipus_on_fire. Never knew strip() is this powerful. I was in a idea that strip is just to remove unwanted elements.

Comment: It's not `strip()`, it's `.text`. `strip()` just cleans out the eventual pre/post spaces.

Comment: but better use `.get_text(strip=True)`

Comment: Indeed - it looks like `get_text(strip=True)` also strips the extra spaces from **within** the document: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39870290/how-to-strip-line-breaks-from-beautifulsoup-get-text-method